# How can I allow "Mixed Active Content" so that my website deployed on Firebase Hosting can make HTTP requests to my local server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, firebase-hosting

I've a React app deployed on Firebase Hosting. It calls a server running on another machine on the same network. The server uses a hardware radio to communicate with some other devices, so it must run on the machine with the radio attached to it.

The frontend sends requests to the server to communicate using its radio.

When I deploy the frontend on firebase and set the ip of the server, I get "Blocked loading mixed active content...".

As far as I know, this is because my server is not HTTPS.

How can I fix this? thank you